# Trying to get a String as the output of SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql

```
con.query('SELECT location FROM TOC WHERE name = "The Story"', function(err, value){
        console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
        console.log(value);
```

This gives me the output as-
[ RowDataPacket {
    location: '/opt/lampp/htdocs/chat/Public/30 seconds to mars - The Story.mp3' } ]

But I want the output in the form of a String.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a string of the data you can `JSON.stringify(value[0])` and log that.

You can also access the value of location by using `value[0].location`, the `RowDataPacket` should be an object where each column is a property of said object, and the value from the row is the value of the property

Comment: value.location gives the output as undefined.

Comment: Also I just want -/opt/lampp/htdocs/chat/Public/30 seconds to mars - The Story.mp3 (which is the value of the name- location of the object-value.
Which am unable to get.

Comment: @ArpitBahety Try taking the first element of value and doing the stuff I said, totally forgot it returns an array of RowDataPackets even if there is only one actual row that matches the query