# Cannot Get Alexa Skill to Speak Results of MySQL Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

My Alexa skill runs Node.JS hosted in Lambda. I have successfully connected the code to an AWS MySQL database via the MySQL module. However, I can't get Alexa to speak the results of my query. She simply says, "There was a problem with the requested skill's response."

My console log reflects the value of my database field, so I know the connection is being established successfully. What's going wrong?

```
connection.query('SELECT versetext FROM myverses WHERE id = 3', 
function (error, results, fields) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0].versetext));
var saythis = JSON.stringify(results[0].versetext);
connection.end();
  this.emit(':tell', saythis);

});
```

Here is my console log:

```
 Response:
null

Request ID:
"c05ef0f2-0d37-11e8-94ae-e12579c1d8d5"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: c05ef0f2-0d37-11e8-94ae-e12579c1d8d5 Version: $LATEST
2018-02-09T01:22:56.149Z    c05ef0f2-0d37-11e8-94ae-e12579c1d8d5    "Sample value."
END RequestId: c05ef0f2-0d37-11e8-94ae-e12579c1d8d5
REPORT RequestId: c05ef0f2-0d37-11e8-94ae-e12579c1d8d5  Duration: 2026.02 ms    Billed Duration: 2100 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 45 MB
```

Comment: Maybe the results from the query need to be parse-d and stringify-d, and then pass a string as an argument of emit.

Comment: I'm new at this. Can you provide some example code on how to do that?

Comment: Maybe you have to structure it in json in your lambda response like: https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/tutorials/fact-skill-4?  My guess would be it is related somewhere in there, but digging around the documentation is all part of the job.

Comment: The query isn't returning just the string 'my test value', that string is in the query result, but it's bundled up in an array of RowDataPacket. I think the problem that needs to be solved (just guessing here) is to *extract* the simple string `'my test value'` from the query results. Maybe search stackoverflow for "string rowdatapacket" and look at questions like this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392568/trying-to-get-a-string-as-the-output-of-sql-query

Comment: @spencer7593 See my updated code and logs, above. It seems I have successfully extracted the string, but Alexa's response is still null.

Comment: Oddly enough, I get a null response even when using `this.emit(':tell', "hello.");`.

Answer (score 0):

query is async which means the function returns before the query returns its results, you will have to use a promise to fulfill the request

```
var prom = new Promise((success,reject) => {

connection.query('...',  (errr, result, fields) => {

   speechText = result[0].versetext;
   connection.end();
   var ret = handlerInput.responseBuilder
   .speak(speechText)
   .reprompt(speechText)
   .getResponse();

   success(ret);

  });

});

return prom;
```